# Trying to use left join but encountering syntax error,

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to join a few columns but encountered syntax error at the start "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "id"
 ON (E."id" = F."id")".Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my query?

```
CREATE VIEW "VW_X" AS

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT "id",
    "name"
     FROM "TBL_A") E
LEFT JOIN (SELECT "id"
    "name",
    "school",
    "email",
    FROM "TBL_B") F
ON (E."id" = F."id")
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra comma after "email", I guess that's probably why you're getting that error. You will also have duplicates on the external select (you have "id" and "name" on both tables).

I think you could write the query in a simpler way though:

```
CREATE VIEW "VW_X" AS
SELECT a.id,
       a.name as name_a,
       b.name as name_b,
       b.school,
       b.email
  FROM TBL_A a
  LEFT JOIN TBL_B b
    ON a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: I'm not sure you're right about quoting "E.id"; wouldn't that look for a column whose name had a literal dot in it?

Comment: @IMSoP thanks for the message, I remembered wrong. I updated the answer. I guess the error comes from the extra comma then

Answer (score 1):

i think you just have just put your brackets in incorrectly this query should work. (i have made the query a little more simpler for you)

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name as name_a,
       b.name as name_b,
       b.school,
       b.email
         FROM TBL_A a
         LEFT JOIN TBL_B b ON a.id = b.id
```